# Errors when passing SharedPreferences to an Array to CustomListView (Android - Eclipse)

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have saved some Strings to Keys in SharedPreferences and I'm now trying to copy these Strings into an Array. The below code should check if the String saved to the iᵗʰ Key is blank or not - if it isn't the String should be written to the iᵗʰ element of the Array, and if it is blank the String "Empty slot" should be written to that element.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences saveditems = getSharedPreferences("SavedItems", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    for(int i = 0; i < saved.length; i++)
    {
        if(saveditems.getString("saveditemsArray["+ i + "]","") != "")
        {       
            saved[i] = saveditems.getString("saveditemsArray["+ i + "]","");
        }
        else saved[i] = "Empty slot";
    }
```

This Array is then displayed to the viewer using a CustomListView which I am using successfully in other parts of the App. The Array is passed to the CustomListView as below:

```
CustomListSavedItems adapter = new
            CustomListSavedItems(SavedItems.this, saved, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    if(position == 0){

                    }
                }

            });
```

However when I open this Activity I get the following errors:

> 01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970): Process: com.petehallw.referencing, PID: 13970
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at com.petehallw.referencing.CustomListSavedRefs.getView(CustomListSavedRefs.java:33)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   01-13 22:08:09.404: E/AndroidRuntime(13970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please (hopefully those logs are clear enough)?

Here is my Adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListSavedItems extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomListSavedItems(Activity context,
String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.saveditems_menu, web);
this.context = context;
this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.saveditems_menu, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your adapter please?

Comment: By the way, you should not compare strings using the "==" or "!=" operators but the "equals" method. Actually it's easier to check if the string returned by "getString" is empty by calling the "isEmpty" method or "TextUtils.isEmpty" method if nulls are expected.

Comment: Ah yes thanks for the tips! I have now included my Adapter

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare the "saved" and the "imageId" arrays?

Comment: Probably the saved[] size is bigger than imageId[].

Comment: That is exactly right Badaro Jr....I should have spotted that!! Thanks a lot to both of you